# search a specific string from mysql database from a number of words stored separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a search function in which i require to search the string which is passed through the ajax call. suppose the word is `Sound & Lighting` and i want to search this in the mysql database table where number of words are stored separated by comma for eg the words stored as `bike,light,Sound & Lighting,roses` i want the word `Sound & Lighting` to be searched from those number of words separated by comma which is stored in database table as a value . I tired using `item_name like '%$search%'` but this also didnt helped much. Any help on this?

Comment: You need a full-text search. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: why didn't `item_name like '%$search%'` help? that should be exactly what you need

Comment: And again we have the drawback with unnormalized databases

Comment: i tried this but no help thats why decided to get some help on stack but ended up on negative vote :( . well @AarolamaBluenk thanks for suggesting the doc. i am reading it

Comment: "no help" isn't particularly descriptive: did you get an error? no rows returned? did you var_dump() the query string?

Comment: yes i got no rows returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(',', col, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', 'Sound & Lighting', ',%')
```

or if you are using MySql also this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Sound & Lighting', col);
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66358/3).

Comment: thanks for the good explanation through the fiddle . And letting me know this `find_in_set` . This is why stack is full of knowledge . Thank You